What does it mean for a spring to have negative stiffness?
When working with 2nd order, linear, homogeneous, constant coefficient ODEs of the form my'' + by' + ky = 0, k is indicative of spring stiffness. The stiffer the spring, the more force it exerts against an object's motion (courtesy of F = -ky). That makes sense: Pull the spring, the spring wants to pull back to the equilibrium. Compress the spring and the spring still wants to pull back to equilibrium.
So what would the spring be doing if the value of k is negative?

Isn't it obvious from the relation $F=-ky$?

Mathematically, yes. Physically, no.

Then your question belongs on https://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Part of math is applied math and math modeling, so I was hoping there were some math folks here with the proper knowledge to interpret the equation in terms other than "isn't it obvious due to the math equation?"

That would simply mean the material "assists" the deformation, producing the force in the same direction as the force applied to the spring.

Is there a common type of spring that does this that could help me visualize this? I've never interacted with a spring that I've pulled and somehow the pulling got easier as I pulled it.

Well we call a spring a spring because they resist lengthening, so we can't use the same word to describe something that does the opposite... anyway, pedantry aside, I don't know of any physical object with that property. It occurs me to though that just as springs are a special case of oscillation/periodic movement, perhaps a negative $k$ could represent the separation of two atoms, say? Not a physicist, but I understand that the further apart they are, the easier they are to continue separating...

I appreciate the thought!

@TheMathPotato whether there is such a system is definitely a question for Physics stack exchange and has nothing to do with maths. I'm not an expert on elasticity theory and classical mechanics in general, but I believe there is a way to compress a beam to get obtain the negative stiffness effect

To the Physics page I go...!
